# How to pass a RegEx backreferences as a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, scope

I'm trying to pass the backreferences to a dynamically-created-function as a variable (so i could check if the backreferences is set and if not throw an error) but i can't find a solution for passing it. How can you make it work???

This is the code:

```js
class regexMap {
  constructor(map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  replace(str){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.map.length; i++){
      var regexp = new RegExp(this.map[i][0], 'ig');
      str = str.replace(regexp, this.map[i][1].apply(this));
    }
    return str;
  }
}
// EXAMPLE:
var map = [
  [/FIND (.*)/g,function(){
    var br = '$1'; // Don't work.
    if(br != '' && br != undefined){
      return 'find(\'$1\');'
    } else {
      console.error('Find requires a string');
      return;
    }
  }],
];

console.log(new regexMap(map).replace("FIND This is a string\nFIND "));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean *capture group* rather than backreference? E.g., are you looking for `br` to be the content of the `(.*)` group?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder "E.g., are you looking for br to be the content of the (.*) group?" - Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fucntion you pass into `replace` will receive the full match as its first argument and then additional arguments containing the contents of capture groups. So you can declare those in your function, then use the function directly in your `regexMap#replace` method. See `***` comments:

```js
class regexMap {
  constructor(map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  replace(str){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.map.length; i++){
      var regexp = new RegExp(this.map[i][0], 'ig');
      str = str.replace(regexp, this.map[i][1].bind(this)); // ***
    }
    return str;
  }
}
// EXAMPLE:
var map = [
  [/FIND (.*)/g,function(m, br){                            // ***
    if(br != '' && br != undefined){
      return 'find(\'' + br + '\');'
    } else {
      console.error('Find requires a string');
      return;
    }
  }],
];

console.log(new regexMap(map).replace("FIND This is a string\nFIND "));
```